# Create live camera filter like native camera app in iPhone

Tags: ios, camera, opengl-es-2.0, cifilter, ciimage

i want to apply CIFilter on camera preview like native Camera App.i know about GPUImage framework but get memory issue at some points,Is there any other way to use CIFilter with live camera preview...

Comment: did you find solution ?